# Почему окно штатного JAVA Swing такое убогое?

Tags: java, swing, gui

Здравствуйте. Я решил начать работать с библиотекой Swing (из по IDEA в Ubuntu). При работе с Form в Designer получается следующее (довольно "стильное") окно
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А после компиляции и запуска появляется следующее окно (уже не такое "стильное")
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ли простой способ сделать так, чтобы стиль запущенного окна совпадал с тем, что в Form. Или может другие способы? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Дело в графической оболочке ОС. Поиграйтесь с Unity Tweak Tool.

Comment: Есть такая штука для swing-а `look and feel` называется. Специально для установки разных `тем` оформления. Есть несколько встроенных на выбор, а в идеиеи вполне может быть своя какая-то. `UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");`

Comment: Пример установки в программе `UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAn‌​dFeel");` Через установку свойства в командной строке `java -Dswing.defaultlaf=javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel MyApp`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Попробуй заюзать это -

```
try {
      UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel());
} catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error in a LaF of executable file");
```

`
на винде выглядит довольно стильно - [image: введите сюда описание изображения]